# Disable font antialiasing in QtQuick Text element

Tags: qt, qt5, antialiasing, qt-quick, qtquick2

I would like to turn-off font antialiasing for a Text element in QtQuick 2.

I tried to set both `antialiasing: false` and `renderType: Text.NativeRendering`

but nothing changes... how can I do that? Is it possible?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am running on Embedded Linux (Qt 5.2.1 cross-compiled using the toolchain provided by Texas Instrument as a part of their AM335x SDK 6.00.00)

Answer (score 1):

`renderType: Text.NativeRendering` should be the best you can get. Now check your system's font rendering settings.

`antialiasing` of `Item` does not seem to affect text at all:

> Primarily used in Rectangle and image based elements to decide if
>   the item should use antialiasing or not. Items with antialiasing
>   enabled require more memory and are potentially slower to render.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#antialiasing-prop

Comment: Ehm... I thing that I was missing... I am running on EGLFS platform on embedded linux... in this scenario, when you speak about "system's font rendering settings" what do you mean exactly?

Comment: antialiasing  Makes a huge different for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to remove the coloured noise generated and have sharper text you can add a transparent outline to a text. That does the job.

```
 Text {
    text: "hello"
    style: Text.Outline
    styleColor: "transparent"
}
```